# messenger rabbitmq symfony 4 ssl support?

Tags: symfony, rabbitmq, symfony4

Im currently working with rabbitmq and symfony4.1 I'v sudied doc about symfony messenger and rabbitmq and there is no problem if you have non SSL connection for rabbitmq. Have you meet any implementation of new messanger symfony 4 and ssl connection with ssl certification options?

With package php-amqplib/RabbitMqBundle there is no problem to work with ssl rabbitmq connection. I wonder why they not impement it on symfony/messenger.

There are custom option to add connection but i see no SSL config...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symfony messenger component require a MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN in your .env conf. This is a AMQP formated URI. You should try to use the AMQPS URI in order to use ssl.

[Documentation for symfony here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html)

[Documentation for rabbitmq AMQPS URI here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/uri-spec.html)

I think that if you use the right URI it will work just fine, without any change needed to your symfony application or rabbitmq (except maybe manipulations to authorize your keys)

Comment: URL is fine but there is no option to attach ssl context which expect rabbitmq server https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html

Comment: Sry my sources were not complete. Here are the parameters you should test in your uri : https://www.rabbitmq.com/uri-query-parameters.html

Comment: Did it work ? I'm curious in case i'd use it or someone else here.

Comment: Update ? Did it work ? I'm implementing this pretty soon, i'd like to hear about it :)